# Defined operator works in main() but doesn't work in class

Tags: c++, operators

I have two classes defining geometric entities: point and plane. I also want to define vector between two points and for this I created operator of substraction within *point* (punkt) class. Here is the code of this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Punkt
{
double x, y, z;

public:

Punkt(const double& xp = 1, const double& yp = 1, const double& zp = 1) : x(xp), y(yp), z(zp) {}

vector<double> global;
vector<double>& operator - (const Punkt B)   // vector A - B returns vector from point A to B
{
    global.push_back(B.x - x);
    global.push_back(B.y - y);
    global.push_back(B.z - z);
    return global;
}
};
```

It works for main() class. You can see below that I have two objects: a,b of type punkt, they are substracted and assigned to vector wek. It compiles with no problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "punkt.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> wek;
    Punkt a(0, 0, 0);
    Punkt b(2, 3, 0);

    wek = b - a;
    cout << wek[0] << " " << wek[1] << " " << wek[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However when I want to use it within *plane* class I get **IntelliSense: no operator "-" matches these operands** error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "punkt.h"
using namespace std;

class Plane
{
Punkt A, B, C;
vector<double> normal;

public:

Plane(const Punkt& A0 = Punkt(),const Punkt& B0 = Punkt(),const Punkt& C0 = Punkt()) : A(A0), B(B0), C(C0)
{
    vector<double> wek;
    wek = A0 - C0;
}
};
```

I would like to ask you why I can perform one operation here ( main() block ) and at the same time I can't do it there (plane class). Also could you help me with fixing the code so it worked without rewriting everything from scratch? I think that I asked you pretty basic question and hope that its a matter of adding one or two lines of code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get a _real compiler error_ also?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. I get error shown above and I use Virtual Studio Proffesional 2013. Thats the only error

Comment: ***I'm not sure if I understand your question.*** IntelliSense errors are not always real compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work in `Plane` since the `Punkt` objects are `const` and the `operator-` function is a non-`const` member function.

You should make `operator-` a `const` member function.

```
vector<double>& operator - (const Punkt B) const;
                                          //^^^^
```

On a related note, why do you have

```
vector<double> global;
```

as a member variable of `Punkt`? That seems unnecessary. You can implement `operator-()` using a local variable. Not only that, you will end up returning a `vector` with 6 elements if you call `operator-()` on the same object twice.

Change it to:

```
vector<double> operator - (const Punkt B) const
{
    vector<double> res;
    res.push_back(B.x - x);
    res.push_back(B.y - y);
    res.push_back(B.z - z);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Great, thankx! But now I have 4 errors within Punkt classs :(

IntelliSense: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> &" to initializer of type "const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>" - under return *global*

Comment: and each one for push_back method:

IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=double, _Alloc=std::allocator<double>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
            argument types are: (double)
            object type is: const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>

Comment: Truth be told I had tried something like you did here (with local variable) but I got warning and compiling got crashed. I don't know, maybe I did something wrong. Thanks for help once again :)

Answer (score 0):

When overloading operators you should prefer non-member functions to member functions and if overloading an operator like 'subtraction' it should mean 'subtract' and should return an object of the same type. In your case i think the ideal solution would be to create a member function called something relevant like distanceTo( Punkt & p ) that will return a Punkt object.

You may want to consider your whole code design by creating a class called Vector3D and using compositional class design, have any geometric shapes contain a number of Vector3D objects. A point has 1, a plane has 4 and so on. the shapes themselves are responsible for using their data.